# Translating points in hyperbolic geometry

Tags: conic-sections

The hyperboloid given by:

$$
x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = -1
$$

can be parameterized as:

$$
\begin{align}
x &= \sinh(r)\ \cos(\theta)\\
y &= \sinh(r)\ \sin(\theta)\\
z &= \cosh(r)\\
\end{align}
$$

Conversely, given $(x, y, z)$ we can find $(r, \theta)$:

$$
\begin{align}
r &= \cosh^{-1}(z)\\
\theta &= \arctan(y/x)\\
\end{align}
$$

Translating an $(x, y, z)$ point $a$ units along the $x$ axis is accomplished by a hyperbolic rotation.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cosh(a) & 0 & \sinh(a) \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\sinh(a) & 0 & \cosh(a) \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
$$

### Questions

---

1. How is an $(r, \theta)$ point translated?
2. Suppose I have the three points $A$ at $(0, 0°)$, $B$ at $(1, 0°)$, and $C$ at $(1, 45°)$. If these three points are translated 1 unit to the right, will $C$ still be at $45°$ relative to $A$?
3. Will the alternate angle to $45°$ be $180°-45° = 135°$?
4. Will $C$ still be $1$ unit away from $A$?

[image: Translating points in hyperbolic geometry]

I've drawn a little picture to help illustrate the problem.

$$
\begin{array}{c|ll}
point & before & after \\
\hline
A & (0, 0°) & (1, 0°) \\
B & (1, 0°) & (2, 0°) \\
C & (1, 45°) & (?, ?) \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: By definition, any isometry (including translations) preserves lengths and angles. That answers your (2) and (4). As for (3), angles in the hyperbolic plane behave the same as angles in the Euclidean plane _locally_ (in the tangent plane at any point); they're only different for extended objects like triangles. So $135^\circ$ is correct.